# Local storage event not triggered in IE 11 Enterprise mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

My web application is running in **IE 11 enterprise mode** as the application is compatible in IE 8 now (i.e. yet to support IE 11).

I am using localStorage and trying to do some action (i.e. redirecting to logout page) when the key in localStorage is changed.

Please note that the below code works fine in **IE 11 (i.e. non enterprise mode)** and **IE debug mode (with version set to 8)**. I am having problem only when the browser is in IE 11 Enterprise Mode.

**I have attached the listener as mentioned below:-**

```
if (window.addEventListener) {                                          
    window.addEventListener("storage", handle_storage, false);                      
} else {                        
    window.attachEvent("onstorage", handle_storage);
}
```

**Function to take some action in other tabs when logout is clicked in one of the tabs:-**

```
var handle_storage = function () {                   
    //some action i.e. redirecting to logout page
};
```

**Set the value in localStorage when logout button is clicked:-**

```
function saveLogoutInLocalStorage() {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem('is_logout','true');                       
    }
}
```

Comment: *"P.S : This is not a duplicate question. I have searched a lot before I post this question."* is not constructive. People will either find an earlier version and helpfully point you at it, or they won't. All a comment like that does is make people walk away.

Comment: Do you know what your enterprise mode is using? It could be IE7 or IE8. In IE7 afaik these events are not supported. And even if, I'm not sure if enterprise mode supporting local storage ...

Comment: @eisbehr: *If* it's emulating IE8, hopefully it does, as IE8 supports local storage (though I've never checked to see if IE8 supports the `storage` event; even IE10 and IE11 have [bugs in the event](http://caniuse.com/#search=stor)).

Comment: Enterprise mode is set as IE8. I am just wondering how it works when I run in debug mode set as IE8? Any other alternate solution available for multiple tab logout scenarios without using localStorage?

Comment: If you can confirm that Enterprise Mode is running as IE8 and not IE7, and you can confirm that normal IE11 in IE8 mode works fine, then it starts to smell very much like a bug in Enterprise mode, in which case you might want to contact Microsoft support. (I'm assuming you have a support contract if you're using Enterprise Mode, so you may as well use it). I can easily imagine it's the kind of bug that might have slipped past unnoticed till now, as sites using localStorage don't tend to be the same kind of sites that have trouble being upgraded.

Comment: Another interesting point, the code seems to be working when I run it in IE debug mode (with option as Edge or 8.. Note: I am using IE 11 browser). As soon as, I switch off the debug mode, the same functionality is not working. I don't have any console.log statements in my code. Even I tried to add "if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}};" in case if it is present in any of the libs. It doesn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was happening for me because the pages were loaded in compatibility mode. Try this in

```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,IE=9,IE=7">
```